# PHP-EWS: Set IsRead Flag for a Message

Tags: php, soap, exchangewebservices

I am writing a php script to read emails from an Exchange Server 2010. Currently, I am able to retrieve all unread emails, but I would like to mark the emails that I have retrieved as read, so I don't retrieve messages I have already retrieved again. I am using [php-ews](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) from github. I created a script to do this, but every time it runs I get this error when I call UpdateItem.

```
    PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'Path' property
    Stack Trace:
    #0 ExchangeClient.php(355): SoapClient->__call('UpdateItem', Array)
    #1 ExchangeClient.php(355): NTLMSoapClient->UpdateItem(Object(UpdateItemType))
    #2 markReadTest.php(20): ExchangeClient->mark_as_read(Object(stdClass))
    #3 ExchangeClient.php on line 355
```

I'm note sure what is causing this error because I think all of my SOAP nesting is correct because I have been referring to [Microsoft's EWS SOAP reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa581084(v=exchg.150).aspx) for the UpdateItem function. Here is the code for the script that I am using to mark messages as read.

```
   public function mark_as_read($ReadMessage)
   {
      $request = new EWSType_UpdateItemType();
      $request->MessageDisposition = 'SaveOnly';
      $request->ConflictResolution = 'AlwaysOverwrite';
      $request->ItemChanges = array();

      $change = new EWSType_ItemChangeType();
      $change->ItemId = new EWSType_ItemIdType();
      $change->ItemId->Id = $ReadMessage->ItemId->Id;
      $change->ItemId->ChangeKey = $ReadMessage->ItemId->ChangeKey;

      $field = new EWSType_SetItemFieldType();
      $field->FieldURI = new EWSType_PathToUnindexedFieldType();
      $field->FieldURI->FieldURI = 'message:IsRead';
      $field->Message = new EWSType_MessageType();
      $field->Message->IsRead = True;

      $change->Updates->SetItemField[] = $field;

      $request->ItemChanges[] = $change;

      $response = $this->client->UpdateItem($request);
      return $response;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a comment that provided the solution on a [howtoforge post](https://www.howtoforge.com/talking-soap-with-exchange) about connecting to EWS through the PHP SOAPclient. The solution was to replace the path element with FieldURI elements in the **types.xsd** file.

Original XML Tag:

```
<xs:element ref="t:Path"/>
```

Replaced By:

```
<xs:element ref="t:FieldURI"/>
<xs:element ref="t:IndexedFieldURI"/>
<xs:element ref="t:ExtendedFieldURI"/>
```

This path element occurred 8 times in my version of types.xsd which I got from an Exchange-2013 SP1 server and I replaced all instances of it with the FieldURI elements. After, I did this I was able to mark emails as read without modifying the code I used in my question

Answer (score 0):

Two things that maybe doing it first you should be setting the IsReadSpecified property to true eg

```
$request = new EWSType_UpdateItemType();
$request->MessageDisposition = 'SaveOnly';
$request->ConflictResolution = 'AlwaysOverwrite';
$request->ItemChanges = array();

$change = new EWSType_ItemChangeType();
$change->ItemId = new EWSType_ItemIdType();
$change->ItemId->Id = $ReadMessage->ItemId->Id;
$change->ItemId->ChangeKey = $ReadMessage->ItemId->ChangeKey;

$field = new EWSType_SetItemFieldType();
$field->FieldURI = new EWSType_PathToUnindexedFieldType();
$field->FieldURI->FieldURI = 'message:IsRead';
$field->Message = new EWSType_MessageType();
$field->Message->IsReadSpecified = true;
$field->Message->IsRead = true;

$change->Updates->SetItemField[] = $field;

$request->ItemChanges[] = $change;

$response = $this->client->UpdateItem($request);
return $response;
```

Also you might want to look at what the request SOAP is your code is submitting to the server and post that. Its generally a lot clearer from the SOAP what you are doing incorrectly.

Comment: I have tried dumping the XML sent and received from the server by using SoapClient's `__getLastRequest()` and `__getLastResponse()` functions. However, my code is failing before the request is even sent. I'll update my question with the stack trace that shows this that I left out initially.